# Name of Home directory of previous owner of MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I purchased this MacBook Pro with Snow Leopard which I upgrade to El Capitan. Then changed the previous Account name to to my name, but still have the previous owner name under:

> System Preference > Users & Groups > UserName > Advance Options, Home directory

What is the correct thing to do with this since I want my own home directory. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your own home directory by making a new folder and clicking "Choose..." next to home directory.

For example:

Create a new folder at `/Users/YourName`
Open System Preferences > Users & Groups > YourUsername > Advanced Options > Home Directory > Choose...
Choose the folder you just created

You will probably have to move all your data to the new directory. You can delete the old folder after making sure that all your data is secure.

**Note:** as mentioned in another answer, doing a clean install would be a good idea. A simple internet search will yield many results that can help you. Make sure you have a backup.

Comment: Thanks :), do I need to do anything about the UUID?

Comment: I don't think so. I once changed the home directory of a user and didn't change anything else and the user works fine, so I wouldn't touch any of the other options. After all, that warning is there for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

The correct thing to do is wipe the machine & start over.
That way you would at least own the OS.

Right now, everything on there is registered to its previous owner, which is going to cause problems for updates, even OS updates, unless you also know the previous owner's Apple ID & password [which I sincerely hope you don't]

Apple & Microsoft run opposite paradigms, Windows essentially ties everything to the machine, Apple ties it to the owner.
This makes moving machines very easy on Apple, but changing owners much more difficult, & in many cases impossible.