# How to log in to a Mac OSX desktop with no user account password?

Tags: macos, mac, login-screen, setup

My mom was nice enough to give me her boss's old Mac OS X desktop. The issue is I have no information about login names or password. I can turn it on and off and that is all.

How can I login and get my account set up?

Comment: You really should wipe the machine & start over. See my answer at http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/222788/85275

Answer (score 2):

Resetting User Account Password (10.7 +)

1) Boot into your Recovery Partition holding down command + R at the startup chime

2) Select 'Terminal' from your Utilities Menu Bar

3) Type the following command in: 
     resetpassword

4) From the window that appears, select your boot volume and the appropriate user account

5) Type in the new password and confirm the new password

6) Click Save, close this pane and quit Utilities

7) Select your boot volume when presented with choose startup disk and reboot your machine